# Using MemoryCache with NServiceBus - what's the best approach?

Tags: c#, caching, nservicebus, messaging, memorycache

I use NServiceBus in my project and everytime the app receives a message it constructs the instance of the class again and again.
And I want it to store somewhere some initially loaded information for the further use.
I can't instantiate the memory storage in the Handler class , and I can't use the database because it's too slow.
I think of using the MemoryCache but I need to have access to it from the Hander.
Please advise what is the best way to do it.

Here's my code:

```
//this is a console app
class Program{
...
}

//this is a Handler of NServiceBus:
public class MyCommandHandler: IHandleMessages<MessageCommand>
{
public Task Handle(MessageCommand message, IMessageHandlerContext context)
{
        ...

return context.Publish(obj);
}
}//class
```

Comment: So, to understand correctly, instantiating the message is a very performance heavy operation?

Comment: The message is going to be processed using some services and some additionally loaded havy data like some kinda in-memory database. It's used to prepare another message. So the question is how to organize the instantiation of the storage. If I create the ObjectCache in the constructor of the Handler, then it will be re-created for every message and I want to avoid it.

Comment: So how slow is it, and how fast does it have to be? If you can't answer these questions then this is probably a case of premature optimisation

Answer (score 2):

If ObjectCache is [registered as a single instance](https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/containers/#dependency-lifecycle-singleinstance) it can then be injected into all handlers by [including it as a constructor parameter](https://docs.particular.net/samples/containers/autofac/#injecting-the-dependency-in-the-handler)

Comment: I also thought about this but maybe there is another way, more optimized?

Comment: best way i know of :)